# Outlook 2013 updating inbox but no new items

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, troubleshooting

I have Outlook 2013 with an Exchange account configured. Nothing has changed but suddenly I am getting the message "UPDATING Inbox (980 MB)" in the status bar.

There is constant progress in the download, yet I see no new items being added to the inbox. The attachment policy wouldn't have allowed an attachment that large, and I see no new mail in OWA.

Furthermore, I have tried setting Outlook to download headers only, but it continues to update the inbox. I check the status of the update and I find that it just says "Synchronizing server changes in folder 'Inbox'".

Any ideas how I can find out what is being downloaded that is so large? How can I stop it?